# Python re.split() on spaces while treating quoted strings atomically

Tags: python, regex

So I've seen this subject discussed before, but the requirements were always a bit more relaxed than what I need. What I am looking for is a regexp pattern that will split on spaces while treating quoted substrings atomically. However, I am looking for a solution which:

1. Is a *single* regex pattern and a *single* call to re.split(), because...
2. I need it to work with the maxsplit argument.

Example:

```
s = 'chat "john doe" Use "foo or bar",   not  "baz and gruz" .'

results = re.split(PATTERN, s, maxplit=2)
```

results should be:

```
['chat', '"joe doe"', 'Use "foo or bar",   not  "baz and gruz" .']
```

All of the solutions I've seen so far to this kind of problem have either involved re.findall() or list comprehensions to extract empty strings from the results of re.split(), both of which eliminate the ability to use the maxsplit feature. And I don't want to write a function of my own to do what maxsplit already does with re.split()--the important aspect of which, in this use-case, is that multiple spaces are preserved when they are past the maxsplit boundary, as shown in my example.

EDIT:
So I found a way to adapt a previous solution:

```
def mysplit(s, maxsplit=0):
    PATTERN = r"(\s|\".*?\"|'.*?')"
    return [p for p in re.split(PATTERN, s, maxsplit=maxsplit) if p.strip()]
```

Comment: why `"foo or bar"` not a match?

Comment: your output string doesn't match your input string

Comment: @famousgarkin About your last point, I think he's referring to the `maxsplit` argument. Only the first two splits are processed, and the rest are in one string at the end.

Comment: why last dot is not a separate match?

Comment: Because the maxsplit argument to re.split() stops splitting after the second space.

Comment: Why does it need to be a regex? Why do you need maxsplit?  The shlex module does this very nicely in Python without difficult regex shenanigans.  Use shlex.split(), then re-combine the pieces at the end to simulate maxsplit.

Comment: Solutions that re-combine pieces--produced by splitting on every space--loses whatever embedded strings of consecutive spaces (beyond one) existed in the portion of the original string that was not meant to be split in the first place. That changes the unsplit portion in undesirable ways.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to use a **Negative Lookahead** here:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'chat "john doe" Use "foo or bar",   not  "baz and gruz" .'
>>> results = re.split(r' +(?![^"]*"(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)', s, 2)
>>> results

['chat', '"john doe"', 'Use "foo or bar",   not  "baz and gruz" .']
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking for is a regexp pattern that will split on spaces while treating quoted substrings atomically

This should work. Split it by matched spaces.

```
(?<=\S)\s(?=\")|(?<=\")(?!\S+)\s
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/mF8bJ7/3)

Comment: Won't this fail for malformed (but possibly correct) strings like `this quoted text contains " a leading space"`?

Answer (score 0):

You can check that the space you are matching is outside of quotation marks by checking if it is *preceded* by an even number of quotation marks. So the following regular expression will only match spaces outside of quotation marks:

```
PATTERN = r'(?<=(.*?".*?".*?)*)\s'
```

Comment: I get a syntax error when trying to compile that in Python 3.4

Comment: Did you escape the quotes if you are surrounding the string with double quotes?

Comment: I did `pat = re.compile(r'''(?<(.*?".*?".*?)*)\s''')`

Comment: "look-behind requires fixed-width pattern"

Comment: I always forget that. I'll delete when I can.

Comment: Note that the `regex` module will work with a variable-width lookbehind